# Hotlink redirection

Tags: image, http-headers

I have this URL: **www.example.com/yyy.gif** at my site.
It is actually NOT a direct link to the image  but a HTML page containing the image (direct url to said image is www.example.com/files/yyy.gif). I want to keep it that way.

**THE PROBLEM**

When the link (www.example.com/yyy.gif) is posted somewhere (forums, comments at various websites) it is quite common that their script assumes it is a direct link to an image and tries to display it as an image (`<image src="www.example.com/yyy.gif">`) which leads to broken image on their site.

**THE QUESTION**

Is there a way to detect these cases and automatically reroute them to the direct image URL? Keep in mind that visitors should be able to open the original URL without being redirected.

Comment: Would HTTP referrer checking be sufficient for you?  That is, if the referrer is not www.example.com then you do an internal (server-side) redirect to www.example.com/files/yyy.gif

Comment: No, the ideal behavior would be that the internal redirect is made only when **www.otherexample.com** is hotlinking to me with `<img src="www.example.com/yyy.gif">`, BUT no redirect is made when the user clicks on `<a href="www.example.com/yyy.gif">` posted on **www.otherexample.com** . I'm not sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it!

So I checked what request headers are generated when the same URL is accessed by clinking on a link and when it is loaded using the `<img>` tag.

The only parameter that differs is "Accept". When the URL was accessed by `<img>` it was `*/*` (Chrome, IE, Safari) or `image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5` (FF).

But when accessed by clicking on a link (or just opening the URL directly), it is something like this `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

So I'm checking for 'text/html' in my script before outputting any content. If it is present, I output the html version; otherwise go for the image directly.

And it seems to be working exactly as I wanted (yay!).

**Could there be any pitfalls that I should be aware of?**

Comment: I don't think you can rely on that, unfortunately.  There's no reliable way of telling how the source client (browser) is requesting the file...even referrer is not guaranteed to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable to see if the url originates from your site.

If it doesn't, output some headers for the image and then the image itself instead of what you would normally do.

Comment: In this case, the user would also get _directly_ to the image if he came from a link (`<a>`) posted on some other site. I don't want that. I'm starting to think that what I'm trying to accomplish isn't even theoretically possible.